# Get href value from a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to take out the **href** value from a variable which contains a link.

This is my variable which contains a link.

```
var mylink = "<a href='#!takethisout'><img src='http://google.com/'></a>"
```

I tried to get the value   **#!takethisout** , and I also googled it but there are bunch of pages with how to get the href value from a real link.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: from mylink variable `mylink.split(/href='(.*?)'/)[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about string split?

```
var hrefAttr = mylink.split(/href='(.*?)'/)[1]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SzHLu/

Comment: in this case <a href=#!foobar>, .match will throw error becouse it can't find match, .split will return undefined and it won't break rest of the code

Answer (score 5):

I could be wrong, but I think you're asking for a `documentFragment` so you can extract the `href` from the string:

```
var mylink = "<a href='#!takethisout'><img src='http://google.com/'></a>";
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = mylink;
var href = div.firstChild.getAttribute('href');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/js8r2/

Comment: Use `div.firstChild` instead. It is faster and shorter.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use jQuery you could do it like this:

```
var mylink = "<a href='#!takethisout'><img src='http://google.com/'></a>";

var href = $(mylink).attr('href');
alert(href);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pn8M4/

Answer (score 1):

You need regular expression to parse part string.

```
mylink.match(/href=["']([^"']+)["']/i)[1];
```

```
mylink.split(/href=["']([^"']+)["']/i)[1];
```

Beware - it **doesn't actually parses html and looking for href attribute** - it will only find string matching regular expression. so in this case

```
<a href=#!foobar>
```

it will NOT work

upd: using split will not break the code in case of non-existent match - thanks @freshbm